# Locate a file and then opening the file using the command line in GitBash

Tags: git-bash

I am new to GitBash. I am using GitBash in Windows 10. I started at the home directory and following are the commands/steps I have followed:

1. ls.
2. cd Documents.
3. ls and found the docx file that I wanted to open.
4. ran open and the name of the document with .docx and it came out bash

> open: command not found.

I am trying to open that file so I can get to the file path. Thanks!

Comment: try with `winword <filename>.docx`

Comment: Thanks stud3nt for the response. I tried that. It is telling me command not found.

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform below steps to add `winword.exe` path in the `PATH` variable and then will be able to open `.docx` files from gitbash.

1. Set winword.exe file location path to `PATH` variable using:

```sh
PATH=$PATH:'/C/Program Files/Microsoft Office/root/Office16'
```

> I'm using Microsoft Office 2016, so your path might differ based on the version of Microsoft office you are using.

2. Run command to open the docx file

```sh
winword '/C/Users/Admin/Desktop/Test.docx'
```

Comment: Thanks stud3nt for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote and Mark it as answer if it has helped.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? And can you make sure if the winword path is correct for your windows ?

Answer (score 1):

**use**

```
start <filename>
```

Run command to open the docx file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).